# Passing variable to scenario in ODI 11G load plan not working

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I have a trouble with passing variable value to ODI scenario. On property inspector for scenario step I check "overwrite" against a variable and then provide as a value #same_project.another_variable. At runtime exactly this string is passed to scenario though I expect it to be substituted by variable value.
Both variables (the one to be set and the one to provide value) are declared in Variables section of load plan.

What can be the reason for this? How this can be fixed?

Comment: If you run the Load Plan with Log Level = 6 you should see which values were assigned to the scenario variables of a session.

Comment: @MarcoBaldelli thank you for your advice. I can see the values and they are exactly as printed in property inspector for load plan step, i.e. #same_project.another_variable. The problem is, the value should be substituted.

Comment: Instead of `overwrite` did you try `refresh`?